# Show all Sub-Categories in Category Module in Opencart 2.0.2

Tags: opencart2.x

By default opencart's category module shows only top categories and sub categories of active category.
And now, i want to show all subcategories in category module, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and couldn't find help via Google.

I tried to remove different lines from file:
...catalog/controller/module/category.php

I REMOVED THIS PART FROM LINE 8:

```
    if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
    } else {
        $parts = array();
    }
```

I was pretty sure that i wouldn't work but voilá, it did! I hope this wan't cause any problems...